# Clone a database schema without any data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need our end-users to "clone" a database from our web application UI. I am able to "clone" a database by backing up a source database and restoring it into a new database. In this way, I "clone" the table schema and data.

My question is - is there any way I can "clone" just the table schema, without the data? I am aware that we can script the database manually, and run that script. But our table schema changes frequently (we add new columns and tables regularly) and we wouldn't want to update this script. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Script to clone database leaving original untouched](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18568633/sql-script-to-clone-database-leaving-original-untouched). you should add some truncate & empty commands but maybe it's easier than start from scratch.

Comment: I believe that question is for "cloning" a database schema and data. In my case, I just need to "clone" the schema without any data. Thanks.

Comment: truncate and delete are easy commands to add to a cloning script. that script is an almost complete base to start from.

Comment: Is the destination database on the same SQL Server instance as the source? Constraints, indexes, security, etc. needed in the destination, or just tables and columns?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same SQL Server instance. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically you have to:

- save the datatase
- restore the backup to a new database (use the `with move` option)
- connect to the new database and then `exec sys.sp_MSforeachtable 'truncate table ?'`

PS: you may have to disable FK constraints if any.

**Antother solution:** use Entity Framework Database First to build a small program. Launch said program with a connection string pointing to a new db.

Answer (score 1):

Right Click over database -> Tasks -> Generate Script

On Set Scripting Options page click Advanced

General -> Types of data to script = Schema Only

With [SQL Server data tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/tools.aspx) you can generate the schema difference and apply only the changes to target database.